# Некорректная работа js в FireFox

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, firefox

Есть скрипт, который подставляет номер дома из выпадающего списка в TextBox , из которого будет сохранен в БД. После сохранения адреса, при заходе на страницу, в textbox будет находится заранее сохраненный дом, все бы вроде хорошо, но хорошо везде кроме Mozilla.

Если зайти на страничку с уже сохраненным домом через firefox, то в textbox будет не сохранённый адрес, а первое значение из выпадающего списка.
Собственно сам код:

```
function onHouseChanged(indexCtrlId, homeCtrlId, ddlCtrlId) {
            $("#" + homeCtrlId).val($("#" + ddlCtrlId + " :selected").text());
            GetIndex(indexCtrlId);
            return true;
        }
```

`homeCtrlId` - значение textbox.

`ddlCtrlId` - значение выпадающего списка.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: На stackoverflow необходимо выкладывать минимально-воспроизводимый пример, чтобы вам могли помочь. html/css/js всё сразу